# Error: cannot find module 'mime'

Tags: node.js, installation, mapnik

I am trying to install cartodb on ubuntu 12.04. I have done all the steps mentioned on https://github.com/danseely/cartodb-install/blob/master/DEV-INSTALLATION.md and I am stuck at the Install Windshaft-cartodb Step. The following steps worked fine:

```
cd ~
git clone git://github.com/CartoDB/Windshaft-cartodb.git
cd Windshaft-cartodb
git checkout master
npm install
cp config/environments/development.js.example   config/environments/development.js
```

Whenever I hit the command node app.js development, it gives me following error:

```
module.js:340
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'mime'
 at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
 at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
 at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
 at require (module.js:380:17)
 at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/Windshaft- cartodb/node_modules/windshaft/node_modules/grainstore/node_modules/millstone/lib/millstone.js:6:12)
 at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
 at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
 at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
 at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
 at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
 at require (module.js:380:17)
```

I installed mapnik using

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mapnik/v2.2.0
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libmapnik libmapnik-dev mapnik-utils python-mapnik
```

Answer (score 11):

@harinish This problem occur due to many reasons, one of the peculiar reason is, if you have different versions of the Node JS installed on your system. Check this [Github discussion](https://github.com/unconed/TermKit/issues/18)

But the best way to resolve this issue of missing module, install it using the NPM as follows:

```html
npm install mime
```

Remember the command install into the current directory from where you are executing this command. If you want to install globally use it with -g switch as follows:

```html
npm install mime -g
```

Then run the program, it will be resolved.